# Authenticating using Temporary Security Credentials

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I've trawled through the AWS documentation but I can't find an example of using Temporary Security Credentials to authenticate to AWS using the `aws-sdk` module, in a browser.

This [page seems to indicate that it's possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) but only links to a Python example that doesn't translate to JavaScript.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the `credentials` object when configuring AWS:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk'

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: {
    'accessKeyId': creds.AccessKeyId,
    'secretAccessKey': creds.SecretAccessKey,
    'sessionToken': creds.Token
  }
})

const ec2 = new AWS.EC2()

ec2.describeInstances({}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log({err: err, errStack: err.stack})
  else console.log({data})
})
```

Would it be possible to get a working example of authenticating to AWS with Temporary Security Credentials, using the JavaScript `aws-sdk`?

Comment: You're not making any request to get temporary credentials in your example; you're just setting static credentials. You'll need to take your existing credentials and use the assume role call to get temporary credentials using STS and assume role.

Comment: @ChrisPollard those temporary credentials are valid, they come from the metadata endpoint from a running box. I can use those credentials from the `aws` CLI no problem. I don't need to create temporary creds, just use ones I'm provided with.

Comment: What problem are you having? Note: If you are creating your client while running in an EC2 instance, you do NOT need to get the credentials from metadata. The client will automatically obtain the credentials. You cannot use those credentials on another system. For the role that you assigned to your EC2 instance, did you assign ec2 permissions?

Answer (score 0):

When using a role that’s attached to an ec2 instance, you can not pull those credentials and use them. Instead, the SDK should be able to handle that. Typically, that means not setting those values. The sdk knows to pull from metadata.

Comment: I believe this is wrong. I've pulled credentials from the AWS metadata endpoint from a VM, using `curl`, and used them with the AWS CLI. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html